# Correr un archivo formateado en UTF-8 con javac

Tags: java, consola, utf-8

Traté de correr un archivo **.java** que hice programé en *Eclipse*, y me saltaron un montón de errores. El archivo que programé, está codificado en UTF-8.

Al ejecutar este comando en el *CMD* de *Windows*:

```
javac C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java
```

La salida en consola fueron los siguientes errores:

```
C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u00bb'
´╗┐package programa;
 ^
C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u00bf'
´╗┐package programa;
  ^
C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:154: error: illegal character: '\u00b3'
        private static void secci├│n(
                                  ^
C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:154: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        private static void secci├│n(
                                   ^
C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:186: error: illegal character: '\u00b3'
                                        secci├│n(matriz);
                                              ^
C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:186: error: not a statement
                                        secci├│n(matriz);
                                        ^
C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:188: error: illegal character: '\u00b3'
                                        secci├│n(matriz);
                                              ^
C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:188: error: not a statement
                                        secci├│n(matriz);
                                        ^
C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:190: error: illegal character: '\u00b3'
                                        secci├│n(matriz);
                                              ^
C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:190: error: not a statement
                                        secci├│n(matriz);
                                        ^
10 errors
```

¿Es posible correr el archivo **.java** con esa codificación?

Además, si intento correr el programa con *java* en vez de *javac*:

```
java C:\ProgramasJava\Main
```

Me salta otro error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class C:\ProgramasJava\Main

Aclaración: Es la primera vez que intento correr un programa desde la consola y no desde Eclipse. Si no es molestia, me gustaría saber cómo puedo correr lo que programé.

Comment: Cuales comandos estas utilizando para compilar y ejecutar el archivo java?

Comment: @David La única manera que conozco es tocando _Run_ en _Eclipse_. Todavía no conozco ningún comando para eso, pero dicen que con _javac_ se compila y ejecuta automáticamente.

Comment: te lo pregunto porque dices que es la primera vez que tratas de correr un programa desde la **consola** y no desde **Eclipse**. Los comandos para ejecutar un archivo java son: **javac {nombre_del_archivo.java}** para compilar el archivo y **java {nombre_del_archivo}** sin extensión para ejecutarlo.

Comment: @David El primer comando es el que me tira los errores que puse. El segundo comando, me tira otro error: **Could not find or load main class C:\ProgramasJava\Main**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto, javac usa la codificación que el sistema operativo tenga por defecto. En windows 10 ya es utf8, pero en las versiones anteriores usa su propio sistema.
Puedes declarar la codificación a usar con `-encoding`:

```
javac -encoding "UTF-8" C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java
```

Si la compilación falla, no se creará el fichero Main.class, con lo que es normal que `java Main` te falle

**Nota**: si te sigue fallando, es posible que el fichero esté en formato UTF-8 pero en el sentido "incorrecto" o use [BOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes), que en UTF-8 es innecesario pero algunos editores como Notepad suelen añadir.

Edición tras comentario: /FEFF es el BOM *UTF-16 Big Endian*, comprueba si realmente no estás usando UTF-16.

Comment: Supongo que ese comando es el correcto, pero me sigue dando errores: `C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:1: error: illegal character: '\ufeff'` **;** `C:\ProgramasJava\Main.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected` **;** `?package programa;` **;** `2 errors`.